# Not able to connect iphone simulator to iphone device in bluetooth gamekit application (iPhone SDK)?

Tags: iphone

Not able to connect iphone simulator to iphone device in bluetooth gamekit application (iPhone SDK) ?

same bluetooth application is installed in both simulator and device, when i am trying to connect device with simulator (via bluetooth), in simulator side(mac system) i am able to get device, but when i select that device, app saying that "Waiting for ******* iphone.." and then after some time, message appear like "Connection Lost". I mean, i am not able to connect iphone simulator to iphone device (via bluetooth).

How to solve this issue ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone Simulator cannot connect to a device through Bluetooth.   From the [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1):

> Bluetooth networking is not supported
>   on the original iPhone or the
>   first-generation iPod Touch. It is
>   also not supported in Simulator.